# how to build 2^n changed word from word with length n in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need a function in sql server to build all of changed word in below example;
for input word with length n must build 2^n changed word;
 For example, if the input of the function is

```
"I"
```

the output of the function should be

```
I
-
```

the input of the function is

```
"am"
```

the output of the function should be

```
am
-m
a-
--
```

the input of the function is

```
"sql"
```

the output of the function should be

```
sql
-ql
s-l
sq-
--l
s--
-q-
---
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a numbers table (master..spt_values) and [`stuff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) in a loop.

```
declare @Word varchar(10) = 'sql'

declare @T table
(
  Word varchar(10)
)

insert into @T values (@Word)

while not exists(select *
                 from @T 
                 where Word = replicate('-', len(@Word)))
begin              
  insert into @T(Word)
  select distinct stuff(T.Word, N.number, 1, '-')
  from @T as T
    cross join
       master..spt_values as N
  where N.type = 'P' and
        N.number between 1 and len(@Word) and
        stuff(T.Word, N.number, 1, '-') not in (select Word from @T)
end        

select *
from @T
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122334/

Or you can use a reqursive CTE

```
declare @Word varchar(10) = 'sql'

;with C as
(
  select @Word as Word,
         0 as Iteration
  union all
  select cast(stuff(Word, N.number, 1, '-') as varchar(10)),
         Iteration + 1
  from C
    cross join
       master..spt_values as N
  where N.type = 'P' and
        N.number between 1 and len(@Word) and
        Iteration < len(@Word)
)
select distinct Word
from C
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/122337/

**Update**

The recursive CTE version is really slow as pointed out by OP in a comment. Using a word with 7 letters there are 960800 rows returned from the CTE.

Comment: @ConradFrix - The order was not intentional :).

Comment: second answer is good but  time for "example" input string is 28 seconds , first answer is very good and time for "example" input string is 0 seconds

Comment: @jozi this is only your unique answer that voted up. and you haven't any other comments that voted up in other stackoverflow pages .. we can calculate and query with data explorer tools in stackexchange . we can query like sql query. but in stack statistics. that is a huge tool. http://data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

This Recursive CTE

```
declare @input varchar(25)

set @input = 'SQL'
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Stuff(@input, v.NUMBER, 1, '-') OUTPUT, 
                0                               LEVEL 
         FROM   MASTER..spt_values v 
         WHERE  TYPE = 'P' 
                AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND Len(@input) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Stuff(cte.OUTPUT, v.NUMBER, 1, '-') OUTPUT, 
                cte.LEVEL + 1                       AS LEVEL 
         FROM   MASTER..spt_values v, 
                cte 
         WHERE  TYPE = 'P' 
                AND cte.LEVEL + 1 < Len(@input) 
                AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND Len(@input)) SELECT DISTINCT OUTPUT 
FROM   cte 
UNION 
SELECT @INPUT 
ORDER  BY OUTPUT
```

produces the following output

```
---    
--l    
-q-    
-ql    
s--    
s-l    
sq-    
sql
```

I leave it to you to put into a function.

See it working at this [data.se query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2316/sample-for-8585831)

Comment: I just have to +1 this as well :)

Comment: its very well but for "example" input string 35 seconds is running time